# AWS EC2 - Will I maintain SSH access launching an instance from an EBS-backed AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm using an Ubuntu machine with Amazon's EC2 service. I've taken an EBS-backed AMI of this computer.

If my current instance shuts down, when I launch an instance from the saved AMI, will I definitely maintain SSH access for the new machine, using the key pair that I use for my current instance?

That is, the ssh program should be reliably running and the key pair will remain, and I don't need to make any changes in the AWS console except for launching the new instance?

The AWS docs do not address this specifically though I believe it will be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key pair remains, and you should have no problem SSHing to it.  To be sure, I usually launch an instance of the AMI saved, before shutting down the instance that saved the AMI. You may need to launch the new AMI in an isolated VPC, or restrict its connectivity so it wont interfere.